# Selecting two adjecent line strings with select interaction in OpenLayers?

Tags: openlayers, select, angular, interaction

I have a map displaying various paths, separated to the segments, which are of type `Feature<LineString>`. We have a request to implement functionality allowing users to merge two neighboring segments. This is done on BE, all we need to do is provide IDs of two segments.

I was hoping to extend our selection, as we do it right now but I'm struggling with keeping two `LineStrings` selectecd

```typescript
this.selectInstance = new Select({
  condition: (mapBrowserEvent) => (this.hasFeature() ? false : click(mapBrowserEvent)),
  style: multi ? MultiSelectLineStyle : ModifyLineStyle, // provides different style for multi select
  // multi: true, // doesn't work for me, lines don't overlap
  hitTolerance: MAP_CONSTANTS.HIT_TOLERANCE, // 10
  filter: (feature) => feature.getProperties()['modelType'] === EntityType.SegmentEntity
  // we display multiple features and we want to select only SegmentEntity types
});

// hasFeature - don't allow further selection until the first one is cleared
// in our case I'm planning to refactor it -> two items + common point
private hasFeature(): boolean {
  const features = this.selectInstance?.getFeatures();
  return !!features?.item(0);
}
```

What I'm capable of doing now is to click on multiple lines, add them to a selection array, which basically gives me their IDs - that's the goal, but they are not distinguished visually. Only the last selected LineString stays color in a "selected" color.

**NOTE:**
I was able to implement multi select like they did it [here](https://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/select-multiple-features.html), but I would like to implement the selection condition as mentioned above and I'm not even sure if it possible to do it this way.
OpenLayers version: `"ol": "^7.1.0",`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to add selected item to collection of already selected items, you can use select interaction `addCondition` option for that. It just has to return `true` value all the time.

In you case select interaction definition could then look something like this:

```
this.selectInstance = new Select({
  condition: (mapBrowserEvent) => (this.hasFeature() ? false : click(mapBrowserEvent)),
  addCondition: (mapBrowserEvent) => true,
  style: multi ? MultiSelectLineStyle : ModifyLineStyle, // provides different style for multi select
  hitTolerance: MAP_CONSTANTS.HIT_TOLERANCE, // 10
  filter: (feature) => feature.getProperties()['modelType'] === EntityType.SegmentEntity
});
```

To clear selection you can use this:

```
this.selectInstance.getFeatures().clear();
```